# SQL: Query between 2 tables

Tags: sql

Table: **matches**

- matchday
- home_team_id
- away_team_id
- score

Table: **teams**

- id
- name

How can I get all the score matches and the name of the 2 teams instead of the id?

```
SELECT m.matchday, t1.name, t2.name FROM imatches m 
INNER JOIN teams t1 ON t1.id = m.home_team_id 
INNER JOIN teams t2 ON t2.id = m.away_team_id
```

My query is not returning rows, so somebody has an idea why?

Comment: Join teams twice.

Comment: This is basic SQL. Instead of posting the question here, you should read an SQL tutorial - focus on join an aliases.

Comment: Moreover, read about left/right join clauses if some data from your tables could be null.

Comment: You are supposed to put atleast a little effort before posting such question.

Comment: What you mean isnt working? Are you getting an error? Not rows returned?

Comment: No rows returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below to join the table twice;

```
    SELECT
     m.matchday
    ,t1.name AS Team1
    ,t2.name AS Team2
    ,m.score
    FROM dbo.matches m
    INNER JOIN dbo.teams t1 ON t1.id = m.team1_id
    INNER JOIN dbo.teams t2 ON t2.id = m.team2_id
```

*EDIT; I searched "sql join same table twice" on this website and got 432 hits, I'm sure a search engine would return countless more. I would advise a little more leg work going forward*